# Apache NiFi . All policies are granted However got error when try to List queue. Insufficient Permissions. Unable to fulfill this request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, apache-nifi

I deployed a secured nifi cluster on Google Cloud Platform
I used Google Open ID as Authentication method.
I logged in with my user and attached all policies.
Everything is working as expected by exception of one thing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTllU.png)
When I click on List queue I got following permission error:
Insufficient Permissions
Node nifi-test-1:8443 is unable to fulfill this request due to: Unable to view the data for Processor with ID b3169c5d-0175-1000-0000-00001734159f. Contact the system administrator. Contact the system administrator.

I can't figure it out. I added my user to all Access policies in the dropdown.

Comment: Which dropdown do you mean? The one you get clicking Top-Right, or the one you get clicking on a Key symbol on the canvas to the right?

Answer (score 1):

All of the node identities also need access to the view the data. In the simplest case there would need to be a policy on the root process group for "view data" which equates to "/data/process-groups/", and it would have your end user plus all the node users.